# Flow for authenticating user with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-login, redux

What is the Redux way to organize client-side user authentication code?

Would also love to learn how to best integrate Facebook login into Redux.

Comment: While this isn't an answer, you might find this sample project helpful: https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux (a SoundCloud client with authentication)

Comment: Also some great tips in this article: https://medium.com/@MattiaManzati/tips-to-handle-authentication-in-redux-4d596e11bb21

Comment: Thanks, @DanAbramov!

Comment: Is it safer to store the access token inside redux instead of local storage?

Comment: @Gixty Redux store is just an object in memory. If you need to persist it, you need to put it somewhere persistent.

Comment: Right! Thanks @DanAbramov

Comment: "Best practice" = "opinion", usually.

Answer (score 4):

In my example project, I simply kept an `authed` reducer that handled all authenticated user data. The initial state and reducer looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
    accessToken: null,
    followings: {},
    likes: {},
    playlists: [],
    user: null
};

export default function authed(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    case types.RECEIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            accessToken: action.accessToken
        });
```

After the user completes the auth flow, I simply set the access token property in the `authed` state, and use that to verify whether a user is authenticated throughout my app. i.e.

```
if (authed.accessToken) {
  // display or do something different for logged in user
}
```

After successful authentication, I also set a cookie. When the user comes back, I read the access token from the cookie and test if it's still valid (for Facebook it might be using it with the `/me` endpoint).

If the user logs out, I simply set the `authed` state back to the `initialState` and unset the cookie.

```
case types.RESET_AUTHED:
    return Object.assign({}, initialState);
```

Simple, but it works for me. You can check out the code here:

https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux/blob/master/scripts/reducers/authed.js
https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux/blob/master/scripts/actions/authed.js

☝ This file is a bit hairy, but just check out `initAuth`, `loginUser`, `logoutUser`, `receiveAccessToken`, `resetAuthed` functions.

Demo:
https://soundredux.io

Comment: Thank you very much @AndrewNguyen, I'm studying your code.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any questions. More than happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't work with Facebook's login flow, but I think it would be the same idea.

So, to log in and store data, just create additional reducer for user with following fields:

```
{
   access_token: null,
   isLogin: false,
   isProcessingLogin: true,
   profile: {}
}
```

Of course, you could have a lot more fields, you could put registering information here as well (for instance, *isUserRegistering*, or *details*, whatever).

All that you have to do – create methods like *logIn* and *logOut*, which will do this flow. In them, just change corresponding fields to update your UI to add loading, error handling, and so forth.

Something like following code:

```
    // action creator
    const logIn = (params) => {
      return dispatch => {
         dispatch({ type: 'PROCESSING_LOGIN' });
         makeAPICall(params)
            .then(
                res => dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS_LOGIN', payload: res }),
                err => dispatch({ type: 'FAIL_LOGIN', payload: err })
            );
      };
    };

    // reducer
    ['PROCESSING_LOGIN'](state) => {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
           isProcessingLogin: true
        });
    },
    [SUCCESS_LOGIN](state, action) => {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isLogin: true,
            isProcessingLogin: false,
            access_token: action.payload.meta.access_token
        });
    }
```

I have to mention, that building middleware to always append token could be not so good idea, if your requests have to be differentiating inside reducers whether they are with token or not – so, it could be a bit more flexible to add token by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I typically handle auth within a session reducer, and then define an `authorized` middleware function for checking whether certain conditions have been met, and if not, redirect. Its worked pretty well thus far.

Edit, with simple example:

```
export default function authorized(store) {
  return (next) => {
    return (action) => {
      const { session: { loggedIn }} = store.getState()

      if (!loggedIn) {
        const session = cookie.load(sessionCookie.name)

       if (session) {
         next(restoreSession(session, activeBrand))

        // Not logged in, redirect.
       } else {
         next(replaceState({}, '/login'))
       }
     } 

     return next(action)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: very good suggestion, same sample code? please